# replace first and second "-" with "_" and ":" respectively using sub in r

Tags: r, regex, gsub, stringr

I have a string like:

```
string <- "a-b-c-d"
```

I would like to replace the first "-" with "_" and the second one with ':'

I am using the following command, however it replaces all "-" with ":"

```
gsub("\\-", "_", gsub("\\-", ":", string))
```

Desired output is: "a_b:c-d"

Any idea is so appreciated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capture as a group and do the replacement

```
sub("^([^-]+)-([^-]+)-", "\\1_\\2:", string)
[1] "a_b:c-d"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost on the right track. Will help you out abit. `gsub` is greedy and thus will replace every instance of the pattern. So you should rather use `sub`  instead.

You should do:

```
sub("-", ":", sub("-", "_", string))
[1] "a_b:c-d"
```

Here you first replace `-` with `_`. Since we are using `sub`, only the first instance is replaced. The string becomes `a_b-c-d`. Now we just have to replace the first occurrence of `-` again, this time round with a `:` instead